# Javascript not producing the output required

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I want to find the value of `str` variable inside `text` variable and store the occurrences in the `hits` array. I have tried so many times, but with no luck getting this program to work:

```js
/*jshint multistr:true */

text = "tang sit men loop";
var str = "men";
var hits = [];

for( var i = 0; i < text.length; i++ ) {
    if( text[i] === "m") {
        for( var j = i; j < (str.length + 1); j++ ) {
            hits.push( text[i] );
        }
    }
}

if( hits.length === 0 ) {
    console.log( "Not found" );
}
else {
    console.log( hits );
}
```

Comment: We cannot just **UNDERSTAND** what you **mean** - please **explain** what you want exactly. (Even tho the code is there the context is not and that is what is important when trying to help.)

Comment: Really, what is desired output in this case? Are you checking for whole string ('men') or separated letters ('m')?!

Comment: `for( var j = i; j < (str.length + 1); j++ )` if `j = i ` then in your case, its bigger than `str.length + 1`, try use `for( var j = 0; j < str.length; j++ ) {hits.push( text[i + j] )}`

Comment: simply trying to search str in text array and then add it to the hits array. Finally want to print it to the console. If that helps

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pahjtLzh/  like this?

Comment: what is the expected output, an array of characters, a string? something else?

Comment: one line ... `hits = str.repeat(text.split(str).length - 1).split('');` (usual caveats about internet explorer lagging behind the others in standards apply)

Comment: What do you wan to achieve here???

Comment: ie9 friendly version of one liner .... `hits = Array(text.split(str).length).join(str).split('');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes in your nested for loop. Try the following:

```
    for( var j = i; j < (i + str.length + 1); j++ ) {
        hits.push( text[j] );
    }
```

First, you should change `j < (str.length + 1)` to `j < (i + str.length + 1)`. Then you should change `hits.push( text[i] );` to `hits.push( text[j] );`

Following these corrections, the output looks like: **m,e,n,**

On point to mention, you can simply use [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

I could reform the code to this extend but please check your below condtion for the `for` loop--> This condition is faulty `for( var j = i; j < (str.length + 1); j++ ) {`

```
function testingThisOneHere(){
var text = "tang sit men loop";
var str = "men";
var hits = [];
alert("text.length"+text.length);
alert("str.length"+str.length);
for( var i = 0; i < text.length; i++ ) {
    //alert("condition: "+(text[i] == "m"));
    //alert("text[i]"+text[i]);
    if( text[i] == "m") {



        for( var j = i; j < (str.length + 1); j++ ) {

            hits.push( text[i] );
        }
    }
}

if( hits.length != 0 ) {

    alert( hits );
}
else {
    alert( "Not found" );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you were just missing one thing in your inner for loop, the `j` vs the `i`:

1. use `hits.push( text[j] );` vs. `hits.push( text[i] );`

JS:

```
var text = "tang sit men loop";
var str = "men";
var hits = [];

for( var i = 0; i < text.length; i++ ) {
    if( text[i] === "m") {

        for( var j = i; j < (str.length + i); j++ ) {
            hits.push( text[j] );
        }
    }
}

if( hits.length === 0 ) {
    console.log( "Not found" );
}
else {
    console.log( hits );
}
```

Here is the link to the working example: http://jsbin.com/gaxenidalo/edit?js,console

Hope that helps!